# CKFinder 3 'Cannot set property 'filebrowserBrowseUrl' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm new to Javascript.  I've got a CKEditor text box, and would like to add CKFinder to it.  I've followed the instructions found here:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_ckeditor

But when I try to execute the code, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'filebrowserBrowseUrl' of undefined
at Object.setupCKEditor (ckfinder.js:5)

Here is the block of Javascript where filebrowserBrowseUrl is defined:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'current_answer',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl      : '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
    filebrowserUploadUrl      : '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
});

    
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( current_answer );
```

I'm using the latest release of version 4 of CKEditor and the latest version of version 3 of CKFinder.

I get the same error when I comment out this line:

```
filebrowserBrowseUrl      : '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like CKEDITOR.replace returns an object that you need to pass into CKFinder.setupCKEditor but you're currently not saving it.

Try:

```
let current_answer = CKEDITOR.replace( 'current_answer',
{
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
});


CKFinder.setupCKEditor( current_answer );
```